# Finance - If statement for Portfolio Rentability in R

Tags: r, if-statement, finance

I have the following sampled dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(Data = structure(c(1623888000, 1629158400, 1629158400
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Client = c("Client1", 
"Client1", "Client1"), Fund = c("Fund1", "Fund1", "Fund2"), Nature = c("Application", 
"Rescue", "Application"), Quantity = c(433.059697, 0, 171.546757
), Value = c(69800, -70305.67, 24875), `NAV Yesterday` = c(162.40991399996, 
162.40991399996, 145.044589000056), `NAV in Application Date` = c(161.178702344125, 
162.346370458944, 145.004198476337), `Var NAV` = c(0.00763879866215962, 
0.00039140721678275, 0.000278547270652531), `Var * Value` = c(533.188146618741, 
-27.5181466187465, 6.92886335748171), FinalValue = c(70333.1881466187, 
-70333.1881466187, 24881.9288633575), `Rentability WRONG` = c(0.0210345899274819, 
0.0210345899274819, 0.0210345899274819)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Explaining the data: A client investments portfolio, with Ins/Positive Cash Flows/Applications and Outs/Negative Cash Flows/Rescues. This client has put money in Fund1, earned some profit and rescued everything two months later to then put money in Fund2.

NAV means the Funds' value

My question is:
I was calculating the rentability by doing

```
(sum(df$FinalValue)/sum(df$Value))-1
```

but it gives me a wrong result and a very high interest.

The correct calculation for real rentability probably is:

```
((70305+24881)/(69800+24875)) - 1 = 0,005397
```

How can I program a logic that do this everytime I have a Rescue with Quantity = 0? Cause I have other clients and some of them don't have rescues or have rescues with quantity > 0, so the formula `(sum(df$FinalValue)/sum(df$Value))-1`  fit well for those cases, only the Quantity = 0 is screwing my code.

Comment: Please explain the logic used to take these `((70305+24881)/(69800+24800))` values. Furthermore I don't find `24800` in your dataset. Did you misstyped `24875.00`?

Comment: Yeah, that is 24875 indeed. The correct rentability calculation involves the final values divided by the initial values without rentabilization/profit applied... So 70305 is the fund 1 value with profits (which is completely rescued but have to be in this calculation anyway), the 24881 value is Fund2 value plus its profit

Comment: is `70305` actually `70333`?

Comment: No. 70305 is correct. The 7033 is the value plus it profit so when I do a group_by Fund in FinalValue column I don't see Fund1 anymore (cause it's not in the portfolio and I just use it to calculate the real rentability, which includes the profit earned by the older funds too)

Comment: 70305 is 69800 * (NAVApplicationDate for 70305 / NAVApplicationDate for 69800), which is the correct calculation if I would do this manually

Comment: It seems your calculation is more complicated than what I assumed in my answer below. Can you provide the logic for your calculation in terms of the columns that are involved, and which values have to be filtered out? Currently, you calculate `sum(FinalValue + some correction for profit)/sum(Value) -1`, but you perform a correction to get to `70305`. One option is `(70333 + (correction) + 24881.92)/(69800 + 24875 ) -1`. Is the correction equal to `Var * Value (for Quantity==0)`?

Answer (score 1):

To exclude clients with `Quantity==0`, you can either use `filter(Quantity > 0)` or perform on-the-fly filtering if you want to use corrections:

```
df %>% group_by(Client) %>% 
summarize(Rentability = 
   sum(FinalValue*(Quantity>0) + 
          `Var * Value` * (Quantity==0)) /
   sum(Value * (Quantity > 0)) - 1
)
```

This yields `0.00541` (This seems to match the number in your dataset if I don't round)

If you prefer the value to be added to every observation, switch out the `summarize` for `mutate`

Edit: as per the comment below, here is the original answer code, which doesn't take value corrections into account:

```
df %>% 
  filter(Quantity > 0) %>% 
  group_by(Client) %>% 
  summarize(rent = sum(FinalValue)/sum(Value) - 1)
```

Comment: Can you also post the other code you used? I'm testing your code right now for other clients just to make sure I'm not forgetting anything. The code you used previously was the Rentability of only the active funds in the Portfolio and I guess I can use it to make a comparison with my team. Anyway, many thanks for the help

Comment: On my phone now… just put the ‘filter(…)’ statement in front of the firdt group by, and you should the same effect as before. Aldo, if you click on ‘edited’, you can see post revisions